# prevent "[1] + done $scriptname" and "[1] 31303" to be shown

Tags: shell, job-control

I have set up an alias for my mutt: `alias mutt='$HOME/.mutt/run-notmuch-offlineimap & ; mutt'`.

**Note**: Changing my Alias to `alias mutt='$HOME/.mutt/run-notmuch-offlineimap 2> /dev/null & ; mutt'` or to `alias mutt='$HOME/.mutt/run-notmuch-offlineimap 2>&1 >/dev/null & ; mutt'` produces the exact same result.

The script `run-notmuch-offlineimap` looks like that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

notmuch="$(which notmuch)"

$notmuch new --quiet

$notmuch tag +inbox -- "folder:dev/dev|INBOX or folder:pers/pers|INBOX"
$notmuch tag +sent -- "folder:dev/dev|Sent or folder:pers/pers|Sent"
$notmuch tag +drafts -- "folder:dev/dev|Drafts or folder:pers/pers|Sent"
$notmuch tag +github -- "folder:dev/dev|github and not tag:github"


# test if the offlineimap instance of account dev is already running
if [[ $(pgrep -f 'offlineimap.*dev.*') == "" ]]
then
    offlineimap -c "$HOME/.fetch-send-mail/dev/dev.imap" -u quiet
fi


# test if the offlineimap instance of account dev is already running
if [[ $(pgrep -f 'offlineimap.*pers.*') == "" ]]
then
    offlineimap -c "$HOME/.fetch-send-mail/pers/pers.imap" -u quiet
fi
```

(the result would be the exact same if I'd used bash in this script)

When i start mutt, this is what happens:

```
~ 
$ mutt
[1] 31303
Mailbox is unchanged.
# some seconds afterwards:
~ 
$
[1]  + done       $HOME/.mutt/run-notmuch-offlineimap
~
```

The Message "Mailbox is unchanged" is from mutt itself, so that's expected. However, can i prevent the `[1]` messages to be shown? E.g. when i execute mutt, it should only print this (and nothing else):

```
~ 
$ mutt
Mailbox is unchanged.
~ 
$
```

how can i achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are in zsh then you can change the alias to launch the background process with `&!` instead of just `&`. This will immediately *disown* the process.

```
alias mutt='$HOME/.mutt/run-notmuch-offlineimap &! mutt'
```

If you are in bash then you can use `disown` after the command to have a similar effect, but you will still get the first job control message listing the pid.

```
alias mutt='$HOME/.mutt/run-notmuch-offlineimap & disown; mutt'
```

You can avoid both by using a sub-shell:

```
alias mutt='($HOME/.mutt/run-notmuch-offlineimap &); mutt'
```

Comment: Adding () around the script did the trick e.g. `(dowork "$tFolder" &)` instead of `dowork "$tFolder" &`

Answer (score 0):

#### Explanation

The `[1] + done <scriptname> ... [1] 31303` is printed by the shells (zsh) [job control](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Jobs-_0026-Signals.html). This is the result of running a command asynchronously with `&`.

In your case, `mutt` is aliased to `$HOME/.mutt/run-notmuch-offlineimap & ; mutt`, so `run-notmuch-offlineimap` is executed asynchronously and a job control message will be printed when it is launched and when it has completed.

Example:

```bash
$ { sleep .3; echo; } &
[1] 71975
$

[1]  + 71975 done       { sleep .3; echo; }
```

#### Possible solutions

**Unset the `MONITOR` shell option**

```bash
$ unsetopt MONITOR  # or set +m
$ { sleep .3; echo; } &
# (no job control messages)

# reset the option:
$ setopt MONITOR  # or set -m
```

This will suppress the job control messages. Note that also, the job won't be added to the jobs table (`jobs`).

From the documentation:

- [Options, 16.2.7 Job Control](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Options.html):

  ```
  MONITOR (-m, ksh: -m)

      Allow job control. Set by default in interactive shells.
  ```
- [10.1 Jobs](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Jobs-_0026-Signals.html)

  ```
  If the MONITOR option is set, an interactive shell associates a 
  job with each pipeline. It keeps a table of current jobs, printed 
  by the jobs command, and assigns them small integer numbers. When 
  a job is started asynchronously with ‘&’, the shell prints a line 
  to standard error which looks like:

      [1] 1234
  ```

**Execute with `&!` instead of `&`**

The asynchronous command will be immediately disowned and removed from the job table.

```bash
$ { sleep .3; echo; } &!
# (no job control messages)
```

**Execute the asynchronous command itself in a subshell**

```bash
$ ({ sleep .3; echo; } &)
# (no job control messages)
```

(The above illustrates the point, but it doesn't do much sense to run `{..}` asynchronously since the `(..)` (the subshell itself) is not run asynchronously. Hence the full command will block.)

But *why* does executing an asynchronous command in a subshell suppress the job control output? Because: shell option `MONITOR` is unset in a subshell (regardless of setting in parent shell):

```bash
$ setopt monitor;
$ [[ -o monitor ]] && echo "SET" || echo "UNSET"
SET
$ ( [[ -o monitor ]] && echo "SET" || echo "UNSET" )
UNSET
```

**Other options**

Use the [`zsh/sched`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#The-zsh_002fsched-Module) zsh module, or external scripts like [`zsh-defer`](https://github.com/romkatv/zsh-defer) or [`zsh-async`](https://github.com/mafredri/zsh-async).